# Why aren't network requests for iFrames showing in the Chrome developer tools under Selenium?

Tags: webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver, google-contacts-api

I have a use case where I need to retrieve the initiator from the Chrome Network tab. This works fine, except for the following case:

- The iframe is HTTPS;
- The enclosing page is HTTP;
- The page was opened by Selenium

In this case, the network tab (and any extension on the debug protocol) show the fetch to the iframe content remains pending forever, and none of the child loads are emitted.

Changing the page URL to HTTPS, then the iframe is loaded and the child loads are displayed.

If I manually control the Selenium-opened browser and open a new tab, then it does not matter if the fetch is over HTTP or HTTPS. It really is only the tab that webdriver creates when it's loaded that seems to suffer this effect.

Is there some security protection at play, or is this just a weird bug?

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be caused by Out-of-Process iFrame Isolation.

By passing `--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process` to the Chrome process, then the iFrame network traces show up.